# How to export data as CSV format from SQL Server using sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, file, csv, sqlcmd

I can quite easily dump data into a text file such as:

```
sqlcmd -S myServer -d myDB -E -Q "select col1, col2, col3 from SomeTable" 
     -o "MyData.txt"
```

However, I have looked at the help files for `SQLCMD` but have not seen an option specifically for CSV.

Is there a way to dump data from a table into a CSV text file using `SQLCMD`?

Comment: Must this be via sqlcmd, or could you use another program such as the following:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ImportExportCSV.aspx

Comment: It doesn't have to be but I wanted to know for certain whether or not sqlcmd could actually do this before diving into some other export utility. One thing to mention is that it does need to be scriptable.

Comment: There is a SSMS 2008 addin tool that does CSV output from your tables that can be customized by where and order by clauses. http://store.nmally.com/software/sql-server-management-studio-addons/ssms-addin-scripting-tool-insert-to-t-sql.html

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You can run something like this:

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer -d myDB -E -Q "select col1, col2, col3 from SomeTable" 
       -o "MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700
```

- `-h-1` removes column name headers from the result
- `-s","` sets the column separator to `,`
- `-w 700` sets the row width to 700 chars (this will need to be as wide as the longest row or it will wrap to the next line)

Comment: The caveat with doing it this way is that your data may not contain any commas.

Comment: @SarelBotha, you can get around that problem with `'""' + col1 + '""' AS col1`, wrapped in (doubled) double quotes or just call a stored procedure.

Comment: @JIsaak Then make sure your data does not have any double quotes or make sure to replace your double quotes with two double quotes.

Comment: Could someone clarify what is to be done to allow commas inside the data?
Do we have to surround every column with '""'+ ___ +'""'?

Comment: This answer is now outdated. PowerShell scripts are more flexible and can be run in SQL Server as a Job Agent.

Comment: useless, SSMS doesn't quote csv properly when saving as CSV from grid, even when the "quote export" option is enabled,  The export functionality in SSMS also doesn't quote CSV, Microsoft is fail, this method doesn't do it properly either.

Comment: Downvoted because this does not produce [valid csv](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) formatted files.  See the answer which uses `Export-csv`.

Comment: This is not outdated (there's no PowerShell on Linux!) but it doesn't work correctly for several reasons including that without NOCOUNT you'll have the rows affected in your data.

Comment: @Hack-R this worked for me on Linux, but again with the problem of valid CSV (have to use `QUOTENAME` function for every text field): `cat test_query.sql | { /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S 192.168.2.58 -U sa -P topsecret -h-1 -s"," -W -i <(cat -); } | head -n 2 `

Comment: @AlexanderMP Sounds terrible. I can't recall offhand what my solution was back in May, but either I got it to work without QUOTENAME or I must've done it some other way. That sounds like too much typing.

Comment: Remove underline of header: using Select-String -notmatch in the output
get-content Query.csv |select-string "------" -notmatch

Comment: microsoft being microsoft

Comment: python package to convert to valid csv: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71166617/4126114

Comment: @Hack-R I forget when it was released but Powershell is now available on a lot of linux distros: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.2.

Comment: @Ahmed I know, it's late, but anyway - if you encounter commas in field values, you may use another column separator, e.g. semicolon or something: `-s ";"`. Surely you'll need to pick separator that doesn't present in field values, it can be tricky

Answer (score 113):

With PowerShell you can solve the problem neatly by piping `Invoke-Sqlcmd` into `Export-Csv`.

```
#Requires -Module SqlServer
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM DimDate;" `
              -Database AdventureWorksDW2012 `
              -Server localhost |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation `
           -Path "DimDate.csv" `
           -Encoding UTF8
```

[`Invoke-Sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) is the PowerShell equivalent of sqlcmd.exe. Instead of text it outputs [`System.Data.DataRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow) objects.

The `-Query` parameter works like the `-Q` parameter of sqlcmd.exe. Pass it a SQL query that describes the data you want to export.

The `-Database` parameter works like the `-d` parameter of sqlcmd.exe. Pass it the name of the database that contains the data to be exported.

The `-Server` parameter works like the `-S` parameter of sqlcmd.exe. Pass it the name of the server that contains the data to be exported.

[`Export-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) is a PowerShell cmdlet that serializes generic objects to CSV. It ships with PowerShell.

The `-NoTypeInformation` parameter suppresses extra output that is not part of the CSV format. By default the cmdlet writes a header with type information. It lets you know the type of the object when you deserialize it later with `Import-Csv`, but it confuses tools that expect standard CSV.

The `-Path` parameter works like the `-o` parameter of sqlcmd.exe.

The `-Encoding` parameter works like the `-f` or `-u` parameters of sqlcmd.exe. By default Export-Csv outputs only ASCII characters and replaces all others with question marks. Use UTF8 instead to preserve all characters and stay compatible with most other tools.

The main advantage of this solution over sqlcmd.exe or bcp.exe is that you don't have to hack the command to output valid CSV. The Export-Csv cmdlet handles it all for you.

The main disadvantage is that `Invoke-Sqlcmd` reads the whole result set before passing it along the pipeline. Make sure you have enough memory for the whole result set you want to export.

It may not work smoothly for billions of rows. If that's a problem, you could try the other tools, or roll your own efficient version of `Invoke-Sqlcmd` using  [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader) class.

#### Differences between SQL Server versions

As of SQL Server 2016, `Invoke-Sqlcmd` ships as part of the [`SqlServer` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/?view=sqlserver-ps).

SQL Server 2012 instead has the old [SQLPS module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231286.aspx). When the module is imported, it changes the current location to `SQLSERVER:\`. So you'll need to change the `#Requires` line above to:

```
Push-Location $PWD
Import-Module -Name SQLPS
# dummy query to catch initial surprise directory change
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT 1" `
              -Database  AdventureWorksDW2012 `
              -Server localhost |Out-Null
Pop-Location
# actual Invoke-Sqlcmd |Export-Csv pipeline
```

A full path for `Export-Csv`'s `-Path` parameter is safest if you are stuck using the old SQLPS module.

To adapt the example for SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2, remove the `#Requires` line entirely and use the [sqlps.exe utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlps-utility) instead of the standard PowerShell host.

Comment: Other answers honestly suck, this is the only way to do it correctly. I wish it was more obvious though.

Comment: On SQL 2008 R2, I had to run the "sqlps.exe" tool to use the Invoke-Sqlcmd. Apparently I need SQL 2012 to use Import-Module? Anway it works within "sqlps.exe" - [see this thread for details](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/5543dd36-a589-473f-9ad1-6ad4eaf0378c/).

Comment: @Mister_Tom good point. The SQLPS module was introduced with SQL 2012. The answer now explains how to adapt the example for older editions.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for for literally months. wtf why isn't this widely published. thanx X 100

Comment: @JasonMatney PowerShell is the new administrative interface to Windows systems, but a lot of SQL Server advice was published before it became standard. Spread the word! :-)

Comment: Note also that `Get-Location` always returns "SQLSERVER:\" when run from `sqlps.exe`.

Comment: @miken32 always always? I didn't actually test this with sqlps.exe. I'm not in a position to do that right now, so feel free to edit the answer so that it works also on sqlps.exe.

Comment: This answer provides useful information and a powerful and flexible ALTERNATIVE way to handle the issue, however it does *completely fail to answer* the original question as it was specifically asked. I'm a powershell fan too, but let's not let evangelism turn into hysteria. SQLCMD is not going away any time soon.

Comment: The **SQLPS** module has now been supplanted by the superior **SqlServer** module which installs with SSMS 2016, and fixes several serious bugs (including ambiguous versioning, and changing to the `SQLSERVER:\` location at module import).

Comment: @brianary glad to hear it! Feel free to update my answer with the new info and an example.

Comment: @IainElder OK, I took a swing at it. :)

Comment: @brianary looks good! I am not a daily SQL Server user these days, so I have opened this answer up to the community wiki.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a platform-specific solution that does not work on all platform that SQL Server client tools (sqlcmd) officially ships to. In this case - Linux. Plus, it looks more like a postprocessing deal rather than proper CSV encoding at the source, which is likely buggy.

Comment: been struggling with this for a bit, but this answer is perfect.

Comment: @AlexanderMP Powershell pipelines do not use text as format, they actually pass obejcts. So I believe it *is* actually proper CSV encoding and not post processing because the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command can pass the rows as objects in the pipe to `Export-Csv`. Linux pipelines are more limited in this aspect since they are just a way to transfer raw bytes.

Comment: @Giacomo Alzetta I already bit the bullet and implemented a Python tool to do this for me. Super fast. github.com/kfzteile24/sqpy . Easy to install and use, is very small and fast, outputs CSV.

Comment: @AlexanderMP [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) and the [SqlServer](http://sqlvariant.com/2019/03/invoke-sqlcmd-is-now-available-cross-platform-in-the-sqlserver-module/) module are now available on Linux! I can't try it, but you might be able to use this answer there now.

Comment: If you have operators like `>` or `<` in your query you may find the need to escape these with `^<` or `^>`.  In my experience with these commands powershell may not play nicely with these characters, especially if invoking this with `PowerShell -Command "Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query \"...\" ..."`

Comment: Powershell command performs better in producing correct CSV than the `sqlcmd`  version.

Answer (score 83):

```
sqlcmd -S myServer -d myDB -E -o "MyData.txt" ^
    -Q "select bar from foo" ^
    -W -w 999 -s","
```

The last line contains CSV-specific options.

- `-W`   remove trailing spaces from each individual field
- `-s","`   sets the column seperator to the comma (,)
- `-w 999`   sets the row width to 999 chars

[scottm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd/425463#425463) is very close to what I use, but I find the `-W` to be a really nice addition: I needn't trim whitespace when I consume the CSV elsewhere.

Also see the [MSDN sqlcmd reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).  It puts the `/?` option's output to shame.

Comment: @sims

"set nocount on" in the beginning of the query/inputfile

Comment: How can I remove underlining on the Headers?

Comment: @gugulethun : You can do a union in your query to put the column name on the first line.

Comment: This works like a charm, but if you column contains the seperator i get a corrupted csv file...

Comment: Added this comment to the accepted answer as well but... you can get around that problem with `'""' + col1 + '""' AS col1`, wrapped in (doubled) double quotes or just call a stored procedure.

Comment: Downvoted because this does not produce [valid csv](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) formatted files.  See the answer which uses `Export-csv`.

Answer (score 67):

Is this not `bcp` was meant for?

```
bcp "select col1, col2, col3 from database.schema.SomeTable" queryout  "c:\MyData.txt"  -c -t"," -r"\n" -S ServerName -T
```

Run this from your command line to check the syntax.

```
bcp /?
```

For example:

```
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
  [-d database name]
```

Please, note that `bcp` can not output column headers.

See: [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) docs page.

Example from the above page:

```
bcp.exe MyTable out "D:\data.csv" -T -c -C 65001 -t , ...
```

Comment: ServerName = YourcomputerName\SQLServerName, only then it executes otherwise error

Comment: In case you want to see the full documentation for bcp.exe:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: What do you do if you need to export the column names as a header as well? Is there a straightforward generic solution using bcp?

Comment: @johndacosta thanks so much. How would you print the column headers as well? I'm not seeing an easy switch to it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like there is no way to get column names with bcp. And that makes it useless for the case.

Comment: @AndriyK, there is nothing in the original question that specifies that headers are wanted or needed.  It only specifies dumping data to csv which this does do very well.

Comment: @RLH, well, there is nothing that specifies that headers are needed. But in case they are (and I'd expect this to be common case: it's rather normal desire to identify ones data), bcp is useless. That's what Iain Elder and 4 more were asking about, that's what I came here for myself, and I think that this should be clear from answer.

Comment: `bcp` doesn't includer header (column names), but it's ~10X faster than `sqlcmd` (from my experience). For a really big data, you can use `bcp` to get the data, and use `sqlcmd` (select top 0 * from ...) to get the header, and then combine them.

Answer (score 14):

A note for anyone looking to do this but also have the column headers, this is the solution that I used an a batch file:

```
sqlcmd -S servername -U username -P password -d database -Q "set nocount on; set ansi_warnings off; sql query here;" -o output.tmp -s "," -W
type output.tmp | findstr /V \-\,\- > output.csv
del output.tmp
```

This outputs the initial results (including the ----,---- separators between the headers and data) into a temp file, then removes that line by filtering it out through findstr. Note that it's not perfect since it's filtering out `-,-`—it won't work if there's only one column in the output, and it will also filter out legitimate lines that contain that string.

Comment: Use following filter instead: findstr /r /v ^\-[,\-]*$ > output.csv
For some reason simle ^[,\-]*$ matches all lines.

Comment: Always put a regex with ^ inside double quotes, or you get weird results, because ^ is an escape character for cmd.exe.  Both regexes above don't work properly, as far as I can tell, but this does:  findstr /r /v "^-[-,]*-.$"   (the . before the $ seems to be needed when testing with echo, but might not for sqlcmd output)

Comment: There's also a problem with dates having 2 spaces between date and time instead of one. When you try to open the CSV in Excel, it show as 00:00.0. An easy way to resolve this would be to search and replace all "  " with " " in-place using SED. The command to add to your script would be: SED -i "s/  / /g" output.csv. More about SED http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Comment: this is the correct answer, works perfectly with @JimG's addition. I used semicolon for separator, and an sql file for input, the file contained the noncount on and ansi_warning off part, and the -W switch for space removal

Answer (score 2):

This answer builds on the solution from @iain-elder, which works well except for the large database case (as pointed out in his solution). The entire table needs to fit in your system's memory, and for me this was not an option. I suspect the best solution would use the [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) and a custom CSV serializer ([see here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44016589/134930))) or another language with an MS SQL driver and CSV serialization. In the spirit of the original question which was probably looking for a no dependency solution, the PowerShell code below worked for me. It is very slow and inefficient especially in instantiating the $data array and calling Export-Csv in append mode for every $chunk_size lines.

```
$chunk_size = 10000
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM <TABLENAME>"
$command.Connection = $connection
$connection.open()
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()

$read = $TRUE
while($read){
    $counter=0
    $DataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $first=$TRUE;
    try {
        while($read = $reader.Read()){

            $count = $reader.FieldCount
            if ($first){
                for($i=0; $i -lt $count; $i++){
                    $col = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn $reader.GetName($i)
                    $DataTable.Columns.Add($col)
                }
                $first=$FALSE;
            }

            # Better way to do this?
            $data=@()
            $emptyObj = New-Object System.Object
            for($i=1; $i -le $count; $i++){
                $data +=  $emptyObj
            }

            $reader.GetValues($data) | out-null
            $DataRow = $DataTable.NewRow()
            $DataRow.ItemArray = $data
            $DataTable.Rows.Add($DataRow)
            $counter += 1
            if ($counter -eq $chunk_size){
                break
            }
        }
        $DataTable | Export-Csv "output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }catch{
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Output $ErrorMessage
        $read=$FALSE
        $connection.Close()
        exit
    }
}
$connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate option with BCP:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "sp_who" QUERYOUT C:\av\sp_who.txt -S MC0XENTC -T -c '
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually `sqlcmd` comes with [`bcp` utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) (as part of `mssql-tools`) which exports into CSV by default.

Usage:

```
bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
```

For example:

```
bcp.exe MyTable out data.csv
```

---

To dump all tables into corresponding CSV files, here is the *Bash* script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Script to dump all tables from SQL Server into CSV files via bcp.
# @file: bcp-dump.sh
server="sql.example.com" # Change this.
user="USER" # Change this.
pass="PASS" # Change this.
dbname="DBNAME" # Change this.
creds="-S '$server' -U '$user' -P '$pass' -d '$dbname'"
sqlcmd $creds -Q 'SELECT * FROM sysobjects sobjects' > objects.lst
sqlcmd $creds -Q 'SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines' > routines.lst
sqlcmd $creds -Q 'sp_tables' | tail -n +3 | head -n -2 > sp_tables.lst
sqlcmd $creds -Q 'SELECT name FROM sysobjects sobjects WHERE xtype = "U"' | tail -n +3 | head -n -2 > tables.lst

for table in $(<tables.lst); do
  sqlcmd $creds -Q "exec sp_columns $table" > $table.desc && \
  bcp $table out $table.csv -S $server -U $user -P $pass -d $dbname -c
done
```

Comment: BCP allows specifying field and row delimiters, but [does not escape these delimiters if they appear in the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).  So it isn't any better than SQLCmd for creating CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

An answer above almost solved it for me but it does not correctly create a parsed CSV.

Here's my version:

```
sqlcmd -S myurl.com -d MyAzureDB -E -s, -W -i mytsql.sql | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > parsed_correctly.csv
```

Someone saying that `sqlcmd` is outdated in favor of some PowerShell alternative is forgetting that `sqlcmd` isn't just for Windows. I'm on Linux (and when on Windows I avoid PS anyway).

Having said all that, I do find `bcp` easier.

Answer (score 0):

Since following 2 reasons, you should run my solution in CMD:

1. There may be double quotes in the query
2. Login username & password is sometimes necessary to query a remote SQL Server instance

   ```
   sqlcmd -U [your_User]  -P[your_password] -S [your_remote_Server] -d [your_databasename]  -i "query.txt" -o "output.csv" -s"," -w 700
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the python package `sqlcmd-csv` to postprocess the comma-separated output to valid csv.

https://github.com/shadiakiki1986/sqlcmd-csv

```
sqlcmd ... -s, ...
pip install git+https://github.com/shadiakiki1986/sqlcmd-csv.git
sqlcmd_csv out.txt out.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in a hackish way. Careful using the `sqlcmd` hack. If the data has double quotes or commas you will run into trouble.

You can use a simple script to do it properly:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Data Exporter                                                 '
'                                                               '
' Description: Allows the output of data to CSV file from a SQL '
'       statement to either Oracle, SQL Server, or MySQL        '
' Author: C. Peter Chen, http://dev-notes.com                   '
' Version Tracker:                                              '
'       1.0   20080414 Original version                         '
'   1.1   20080807 Added email functionality                '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
option explicit
dim dbType, dbHost, dbName, dbUser, dbPass, outputFile, email, subj, body, smtp, smtpPort, sqlstr

'''''''''''''''''
' Configuration '
'''''''''''''''''
dbType = "oracle"                 ' Valid values: "oracle", "sqlserver", "mysql"
dbHost = "dbhost"                 ' Hostname of the database server
dbName = "dbname"                 ' Name of the database/SID
dbUser = "username"               ' Name of the user
dbPass = "password"               ' Password of the above-named user
outputFile = "c:\output.csv"      ' Path and file name of the output CSV file
email = "email@me.here"           ' Enter email here should you wish to email the CSV file (as attachment); if no email, leave it as empty string ""
  subj = "Email Subject"          ' The subject of your email; required only if you send the CSV over email
  body = "Put a message here!"    ' The body of your email; required only if you send the CSV over email
  smtp = "mail.server.com"        ' Name of your SMTP server; required only if you send the CSV over email
  smtpPort = 25                   ' SMTP port used by your server, usually 25; required only if you send the CSV over email
sqlStr = "select user from dual"  ' SQL statement you wish to execute
'''''''''''''''''''''
' End Configuration '
'''''''''''''''''''''



dim fso, conn

'Create filesystem object 
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Database connection info
set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
Conn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
Conn.CommandTimeout = 30
if dbType = "oracle" then
    conn.open("Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=" & dbUser & ";Password=" & dbPass & ";Data Source=" & dbName & ";Persist Security Info=False")
elseif dbType = "sqlserver" then
    conn.open("Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & dbHost & ";Database=" & dbName & ";Uid=" & dbUser & ";Pwd=" & dbPass & ";")
elseif dbType = "mysql" then
    conn.open("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=" & dbHost & ";PORT=3306;DATABASE=" & dbName & "; UID=" & dbUser & "; PASSWORD=" & dbPass & "; OPTION=3")
end if

' Subprocedure to generate data.  Two parameters:
'   1. fPath=where to create the file
'   2. sqlstr=the database query
sub MakeDataFile(fPath, sqlstr)
    dim a, showList, intcount
    set a = fso.createtextfile(fPath)

    set showList = conn.execute(sqlstr)
    for intcount = 0 to showList.fields.count -1
        if intcount <> showList.fields.count-1 then
            a.write """" & showList.fields(intcount).name & ""","
        else
            a.write """" & showList.fields(intcount).name & """"
        end if
    next
    a.writeline ""

    do while not showList.eof
        for intcount = 0 to showList.fields.count - 1
            if intcount <> showList.fields.count - 1 then
                a.write """" & showList.fields(intcount).value & ""","
            else
                a.write """" & showList.fields(intcount).value & """"
            end if
        next
        a.writeline ""
        showList.movenext
    loop
    showList.close
    set showList = nothing

    set a = nothing
end sub

' Call the subprocedure
call MakeDataFile(outputFile,sqlstr)

' Close
set fso = nothing
conn.close
set conn = nothing

if email <> "" then
    dim objMessage
    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    objMessage.Subject = "Test Email from vbs"
    objMessage.From = email
    objMessage.To = email
    objMessage.TextBody = "Please see attached file."
    objMessage.AddAttachment outputFile

    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = smtp
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = smtpPort

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

    objMessage.Send
end if

'You're all done!!  Enjoy the file created.
msgbox("Data Writer Done!")
```

<sup>Source: [Writing SQL output to CSV with VBScript](http://dev-notes.com/code.php?q=18).</sup>

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be nice. My answer is correct: you cannot do this with sqlcmd. I also offered an alternative way to accomplish the task.

Comment: The downvote is because you clearly CAN do what OP is asking with sqlcmd.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll, He didn't say that one *can't* do it with `sqlcmd`, we was just stating the fact that `sqlcmd` is not properly escaping the comma, thus being barely usable for any *serious* CSV output.

Comment: I did say that, but got tired of the downvotes, so I edited my answer. I'll make my edit more truthful.