# Exporting SQL Server data to CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv

What’s the quickest way to export SQL Server data to CSV with **ALL** column fields enclosed in double quotes, including numeric fields?

In the Results window of Management Studio, I can right click and choose “Save Results to CSV” but it doesn’t enclose fields in double quotes.

I have looked into [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799465/how-to-export-sql-server-2005-query-to-csv) but the solutions proposed does not do what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

Example [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/).

Answer (score 0):

Use QUOTENAME if y ou want double quotes around fields

[Link to quotename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238369%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)