# How can I save the results of an OPENQUERY query to an Excel or CSV file?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to store data from an openquery in a .CSV OR EXCEL FILE?

```
select * from openquery(DB_LINK,'SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 from oracle_table_name')

select * from openquery(DB_LINK,'SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from oracle_table_name2')
```

The result has to be stored in 2 different files.

I have scheduled the open query such that it runs on 1st of every month.
And the 2 files that are generated have to be kept in client's windows specific folder.

This is the first time I'm using SQL SERVER. So please explain step by step.

I am using this query at the moment.

```
declare @title varchar(55) 
set @title = 'Test'   

EXEC sp_makewebtask 
  @outputfile = 'D:\Test11.xls', 
  @query = 'select CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID as [Account Number] from openquery(MSP_PROD,'select CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID from circuit')',
  @FixedFont=0,@resultstitle=@title
```

Comment: `sp_makewebtask` was removed in SQL Server 2008, are you sure your version is 2008? And do you have to implement your solution in this way, or can you just write a small script that connects to Oracle directly and saves the results as a .csv file? It isn't obvious why you need to use SQL Server, and it makes the solution much more complex. But anyway, OPENQUERY is actually irrelevant because you're just asking how to save the results of *a* query to file and that has been asked many times already, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461510/exporting-sql-server-data-to-csv).

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Export Data...` task using SQL Server Management Studio (by right clicking the database), specify that you want to output the data to CSV, and  that your datasource is to be a SQL statement.

Use your `select * from openquery...` statement as the datasource.

Save the package, then create a SQL Server Agent job that will execute it on your desired schedule.

Comment: Where is the Export Data option?

Comment: Right click the database name in the object explorer

Comment: Thankks but i am not getting that option. Please tell me step by step.
I am using it for the first time.
Can i write the open queries in procedure and generate csv file and schedule it

Comment: Ok got what to coose windows authentication or sql server authentication?