# How Can I Export a Record Set to Excel from SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a department table filled with records. I would like to run a query or use the
management studio interface to export department records to an excel file. Format is not an issue, i just want to dump the records into excel. I know i can copy and paste, but this is not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Excel are you using?

Excel 2007 has the ability to read data from pretty much any data source - you can find this on the "Data" tab under "From other sources" -> "From SQL Server".

I'm sure that this functionality is also available in earlier editions of Excel (at least 2003), but I wouldn't be able to tell you where.

Answer (score 5):

**Using SQL Server Management Studio**, consider these two options:

**1.** Ensure you have your results format set to "Results to Grid". Run your query as per normal. Right-click the result set, and choose "Save Results As..." The default file-type should be .csv, and that'll open in Excel without problem.

[image]

**2.** Ensure your results format is set to "Results to File". Run your query, and SSMS will prompt you for a file name, and dump to a plaintext file. Excel will open this, but the formatting won't be optimal.

Also consider this answer from [Sijin regarding setting the output separator when using Results to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799465/how-to-export-sql-server-2005-query-to-csv/799487#799487). SSMS allows you to specify a separator. In this case, you'd want a comma for .csv files.

**Using `sqlcmd` from the command line**, consider this [answer by scottm for another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd/425463#425463).

```
sqlcmd -S myServer -d myDB -E -Q "select col1, col2, col3 from SomeTable" 
   -o "MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700
```