# Generating CSv through a query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

I have created a database, a table, and entries in that table through basic `SELECT` and `INSERT INTO` commands.

To view the entries I am using the basic query:

```
USE test1
SELECT * FROM orders
```

where test1 is Database and orders is Table name.

I can see the entries.

How can I store the results to a CSV?

With the query

```
SELECT * FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '""'
TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

I am getting an error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_ mention your `database`

Comment: `into` should come before `clause`

Comment: Judging from the error message, you're using **SQL Server** - right? There is no `INTO OUTFILE ..... ` command in T-SQL ....

Comment: yup i am using sql server..

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.4984
Operating System      6.1.7600

Comment: Do i have any options of saving a query in SQL server

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/writing-select-result-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

You do have the option to output to csv from within management studio, you can return your grid as normal then right click and click "Save results As..."

or

Using SQLMD as per question [How to export SQL Server 2005 query to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799465/how-to-export-sql-server-2005-query-to-csv)

```
sqlcmd -q "select col1,col2,col3 from table" -oc:\myfile.csv -h-1 -s","
```

Alternative is create it into a variable and then save that via your application e.g.

```
declare @csv varchar(max) = ""
select @csv += replace(column1, ',','","') + ', ' + replace(column1, ',','","') + char(13) + char(10) from orders
select @csv csv
```

Regards

Liam

Answer (score -1):

If you're not as familiar with SQL and would like a more graphical based approach, you could always use the Import/Export Wizard.  Little more user-friendly to people who may be new to SQL.