# How to import 1 million rows in .csv format in MySQL workbench 6.2 ce

Tags: mysql-workbench, bulk-load

How can I import 1 million or more data (.csv format) in MySQL Workbench? Importing small amounts of data is easy but I am unable to store anything as large as 1 million data. The data is in a table with 15 columns and 0.4 million rows.

Comment: Load the CSV directly into your table. Use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement.

Comment: Try this answered question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945348/excel-csv-file-with-more-than-1-048-576-rows-of-data