# Exporting all table's data from SQL Server into Excel

Tags: sql-server, schema, export-to-excel

I need to export data from all the tables in a schema on SQL Server to different Excel files. I only have two software to access the database:

1. SQL Server Management Studio
2. DbVisualizer 6.5

I think latest pro versions of DbV have the option of exporting into xls. How can I do without these?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bcp utility to export your tables.

One table sample in the answer of this question (see `Using BCP (Command Prompt)`):
[Export table from database to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212641/export-table-from-database-to-csv-file)

You should format this bcp command in a stored procedure:

1. Get the list of your tables
2. For each table, export with bcp

See integration of bcp inside a stored proc here: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way is within SQL Management Studio type the select statement 
select * from table. Then select the left upper section of the results grid when all rows are highlighted right click on and select copy with headers. Then paste to excel. I do it all the time. Beware datetime columns as they need to be formated in excel.

Comment: Hey Andrew.Thanks for replying.This is the obvious technique to do that.But suppose if I have thousands of tables in a schema, I will not choose this approach. I need an automated way to do that for all the tables.