# Exporting Sql Server 2008 tables to csvFiles

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, export-to-csv

I need a bit sql to export a set of tables 100+ to csv files.Each table will be a csv file

How do you do it in sql?

I can Import data into sql server using "Bulk Insert" is there an equivalent to convert a sql server table into CSV?

Open to **Free** tools as well

Do I have to reinvent the wheel and write my own little c# smo app to loop through all the tables and write a csv file?

many thanks for your help and suggestions

Comment: If you have SQL Server, you can use the `Data Import / Export` facility in Management Studio, which is using SQL Server Integration Services under the covers. Or you can use the command-line `Bcp` utility to run a `SELECT` statement and output the results to CSV

Comment: In Management studio can you do multiple tables at once? how do you the command line bcp to process 100 table at once.

Comment: No, these operations work on a table at a time - but if you call `bcp` from a batch file, you can call it 100 times, once for each table you need

Comment: @marc_s yes that is the idea.any link with a noddy example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `@scottm` said in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd) you can use this command to export data to csv file .

You can run something like this:

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer -d myDB -E -Q "select col1, col2, col3 from SomeTable" 
       -o "MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700
```

- `-h-1` removes column name headers from the result
- `-s","` sets the column seperator to ,
- `-w 700` sets the row width to 700 chars (this will need to be as wide as the longest row or it will wrap to the next line)

And [Export table from database to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212641/export-table-from-database-to-csv-file) is very useful link.

Finally You can see those solution from [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/546777/HowplusToplusExportplusDataplusToplustheplus-csvpl).

Answer (score 1):

You can employ `Import and Export Wizard` built into `SQL Server Management Studio` that will allow you to export/import a number of tables without writing any code.

You can find the overview in [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx). There is a series of articles there below that goes through each step required to complete the task.