# automatic Export Data From Database to CSV File

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-csv, dynamically-generated

i have to generate a CSV file of full database/table when any new row comes in table.

so is there any script using i can generate CSV file.

i use MySQL to store data in database from HTML Form.

plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a beautiful [tutorial](https://support.spatialkey.com/export-data-from-database-to-csv-file/) to export data from Database to CSV File.

Also one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266993/3976183) on Stackoverflow.

```
sqlcmd -S . -d DatabaseName -E -s, -W -Q "SELECT * FROM TableName" > C:\Test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [Skyvia](https://skyvia.com/data-integration/mysql-csv-file-import-and-export), a cloud solution with native support for CSV file export from MySQL database. Just type in the query or use the Query Designer for a no-code solution then export the results to CSV. See an example below:

[mysql-query-to-csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuvh4.png)

After the results appear, simply click the CSV button and a CSV download will appear in your browser.