# Auto Export Table's Data from MySQL DB to CSV File Periodically

Tags: mysql

So I am working on developing an app, that requires auto export every week at Saturday 23.59 P.M. Is there any ways to make an auto export table's data from MySQL DB to CSV File every week (ex: Saturday 23.59 P.M.)?

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793794/automatic-export-data-from-database-to-csv-file) but it didn't answer my case.

Can somebody show me how to do this case? Thanks in advance

Comment: Write a simple mysql dump/export query to export data in CSV format, then just put that query in scheduler or a crontab for automated backup

Comment: okay I'll try cron

Answer (score 0):

To generate a CSV from your database table, you can use PhpSpreadsheet by PhpOffice.
To regularly do jobs, you can use cron on your server.

Comment: well, cron must be a simple solution for this. I'll try cron