# SQL Server 2008 Standard, get all tables with all columns and possible data within the colums

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reverse-engineering

I am currently working on a big and highly normalized database with 3k+ tables. Besides a small data dictionary there is no documentation which will help me find the right data (it is from a takeover).

Is there any way to create a SQL script which will give me all columns of all tables with all the contents? The result should be the same as grouping every single column alone in every table.

I hope you got me. Sorry my English is a little rusty at the moment.

If there is no way within SQL Server 2008 (Standard), I will create me a small helper in Java or C#.

Thanks in advance! bg Patrick

Comment: [getting all tables and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420741/getting-list-of-tables-and-fields-in-each-in-a-database)

Comment: You might look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39518959/5089204 This solution will return one big XML with the entire database. It was easy to add metadata lile a column's data type. If your db is very big, you might add a `TOP 5` to the created statements. This will return just some rows. Enough to get the structure...

Comment: Hi, if you are interested in the answer linked above, I just edited it to avoid problems with binary columns...

Comment: @user5226582, I think, that your link does not help... I got it the same way as you, but - reading again - I think that the OP wants to get an overview for existing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this. This statement will generate one statement like

```
SELECT colABC FROM SomeTable GROUP BY colABC
```

for every single column and return the whole lot in one single XML.

But be aware that this might get huge and could take hours. For my test I excluded some data types which tend to hold *ungrouped* data

You will - for sure - get the exception, that the generated statement has to many columns. Reduce the input to decent tabel's names or split the query in parts.

For testing purpose there is a `TOP 100` which you'd have to remove and replace by your own logic:

```
DECLARE @Commands TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,cmd NVARCHAR(MAX));

WITH AllColumns AS
(
    SELECT t.TABLE_CATALOG,t.TABLE_SCHEMA,t.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME,c.ORDINAL_POSITION,c.DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c ON c.TABLE_CATALOG=t.TABLE_CATALOG AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
)
INSERT INTO @Commands(cmd)
SELECT TOP 100 '(SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' AS [*]'
     + ' FROM '  + QUOTENAME(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) 
     + ' GROUP BY ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
     + ' FOR XML PATH(''x''),TYPE) AS ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_CATALOG + '_' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '_' + TABLE_NAME + '_' + COLUMN_NAME)   
FROM AllColumns
WHERE DATA_TYPE NOT IN('image','text','uniqueidentifier','datetime','xml') AND DATA_TYPE NOT LIKE '%binary%' ;

DECLARE @finalCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT 'SELECT '
          + STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ',' + cmd
                FROM @Commands
                ORDER BY ID
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,''
            )
          + ' FOR XML PATH(''AllColumnsDistinct'')'
);

EXEC( @finalCommand);
```