# SQL Server - Bulk Insert generated data script in another database

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I generated a SQL Server data-only `.SQL` file with SQL Server Management Studio.

The file is looks like this:

```
Insert Into .....
Insert Into .....
Insert Into .....
```

I have about 950000 rows like that in my file. But when I tried to split the file to 5000 rows part and run it over my local SQL Server, it takes 4 to 5 min for each part.

How can I Insert this file faster? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: how many columns there in this table ? Any triggers? It takes a lot time 5000 rows/5 minutes.

Comment: It has 31 columns. There is no trigger. I'm just seeking for a faster way to insert.

Comment: You will need to specify more information. Where is the data coming from? Is it based on a query? Is it involving multiple tables? What kind of indexes are there on the target table? What disk system is the table residing on?

Comment: You might want to try inserting data into a csv file and then read it with OPENROWSET. The fastest option would be to create a linked server I believe.

Comment: @PawełKucharski Can I change this file? Or I must create new csv file form source DB?

Comment: You would have to create a new file using tips from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212641/export-table-from-database-to-csv-file) question

Comment: How many indexes does the target table have?

Comment: It has 4 indexes