# How to export/generate backup or script using SQL Server using Ubuntu?

Tags: sql-server, database, ubuntu-18.04

I have SQL Server installed in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but I am trying to generate a backup or script for a specific table data for example ***products*** table. I do not know how to generate a script or backup for product table because I have no GUI because it is a virtual machine server. This is how I access to server database:

[image]

I cannot find information in the internet how to generate a script for a specific table since most of the documentation shows how to generate a script using a GUI, but I am not. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bcp` command to import/extract data from your db in a shell script. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-bcp?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Wow worked for me but... the data that I am exporting is very big and when I try to import to another database I get error, I do not know if there are special characters or the table has very big data. I have not marked this as solved because I have not done this yet, still trying.

Comment: how big is your dataset? what is the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Below link talk about this solution and export data to csv file

[Export table from database to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212641/export-table-from-database-to-csv-file)