# How to search commented string in sql server stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 300 stored procedures.

I want to know if the contain a commented out string or not.

Is it possible ?

For example: I want to search whether `--my.dboTbls` is commented or not.

Comment: A similar one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192411/can-i-open-or-save-storedprocedures-and-functions-body-from-msms-from-tsql-no/17192526#17192526 if you want to see the code of all those procs and functions in one place

Comment: would you also want to find '-- my.dboTbls' , or even '/*my.dboTbls*/'  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
Select p.*
From sys.procedures p
Where Object_Definition(p.Object_Id) Like '%--my.dboTbls%'
```