# SQL Database/.SQL File to CSV File

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server-2008, postgresql

I'm writing an application with Ruby on Rails that will take CSV files and migrate data into postgresql databases, however, all of my data is stored as .SQL files or as databases on an MS SQL 2008 server.

I'm wondering if it's possible to write a simple Ruby on Rails script and generate a CSV file from an SQL file/MS SQL database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you mean simple `ruby` script?

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-postgres-sql-output-to-csv-file?rq=1

Comment: You cant make Rails read directly from a MS SQL file without going through a MS SQL Server. The easiest solution might be to export the tables from a MS SQL server and then import those CSV files into the new postgres.

Comment: This [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169220/export-query-result-to-csv-file-in-sql-server-2008) should help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I linked you to a SO thread that will help you get the CSV's exported (see the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169220/export-query-result-to-csv-file-in-sql-server-2008) for ease).  From there you can use your `db/seed.rb` file and do something like

```
FasterCSV.foreach("filename") do |row|
  User.create(name: row[0], email: row[1])
end
```

From there you can simply run `rake db:seed`