# SQL Query, is it possible to export the results on the fly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the query below to get some result but I would like it to be exported to a csv. Is this possible with headers too?

```
Select 
 sys.Netbios_Name0, 
 sys.User_Domain0, 
 sys.User_Name0, 
 sys.Operating_System_Name_and0, 
 arp.DisplayName0,
 ARP.Version0
FROM 
 v_R_System sys
 JOIN v_Add_Remove_Programs arp ON sys.ResourceID = arp.ResourceID 
WHERE 
 Displayname0 like '%Adobe Reader%'
```

Comment: Run the query in SQL Server Management Studio and you can export the grid to a csv file.

Comment: Or do it unattended with SSIS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export query result to .csv file in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169220/export-query-result-to-csv-file-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can try `Openrowset` in SQL

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\Test.xls;HDR=YES','Select 
 sys.Netbios_Name0, 
 sys.User_Domain0, 
 sys.User_Name0, 
 sys.Operating_System_Name_and0, 
 arp.DisplayName0,
 ARP.Version0
FROM 
v_R_System sys
JOIN v_Add_Remove_Programs arp ON sys.ResourceID = arp.ResourceID WHERE 
Displayname0 like ''%Adobe Reader%''')
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: It is missing my WHERE?