# How to improve the select query performance in Java ? Is there a way to do select query using multi threading?

Tags: java, sql-server, multithreading, jdbc, jtds

I'm need to do a select query from a queue I have created in data base , The view has about 30,00,000 rows and is taking about 2 minutes to read this data and storing in local memory using JTDS JDBC driver . The order in which I read data does not matter . Right now I'm simply using a prepared statement and reading from a result set . Is there a better way to read from data base ?
I'm reading from MS SQL server .
The way I'm reading right now is

```
public ResultSet getData(String view_name) throws SQLException { 
    String SQL="select * from "+view_name; 
    PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement(SQL); 
    resultSet= stmt.executeQuery(); 
    resultSet.setFetchSize(8000); 
    return resultSet;
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you're reading the database.

Comment: 1st question as always: do you really need all that data in memory?

Comment: ya i need to store it into a file .

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21286975/1169798 ?

Comment: Is it possible to move data processing part onto database and then just fetch processed outcome?

Comment: I need to calculate some variables using the entities in the DB and store that result into a file

Comment: If I store the query into a file in my system would it take less time to create a file ? I could then read values from the file and process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know the performance of the application will degrade as soon as the size of available memory starts decreasing which will return in more frequent GC cycles.

> Is there a better way to read from data base ?

Did you try streaming of `ResultSet` and the use of Adaptive Buffering? [What is adaptive response buffering and why should I use it?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2007/05/02/what-is-adaptive-response-buffering-and-why-should-i-use-it.aspx)

Adaptive buffering is designed to retrieve any kind of large-value data without the overhead of server cursors. The application can execute a `SELECT` statement that produces more rows than the application can store in memory. Adaptive buffering provides the ability to do a `forward-only` `read-only` pass of an arbitrarily large result set without requiring a server cursor.

When large values are read once by using the `get<Type>Stream` methods, and the `ResultSet` columns and the `CallableStatement` `OUT` parameters are accessed in the order returned by the SQL Server, adaptive buffering minimizes the application memory usage when processing the results.

You can have a look at this MSDN library post for more info on [Using Adaptive Buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879937%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Not sure about MS SQL, but in MySQL streaming of `resultset` can be enable as below.

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                    java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Is adaptive buffering supported in JTDS driver ?