# Automate SQL Queries and export

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sqlreportingservice

I'm trying to automate a SQL query that needs to run on multiple databases. The query is generally run at the beginning of the week manually, ran for each individual database, and then exported to a CSV.

I need to find a simple way to have this query ran and have the result set exported to a CSV for me.

Comment: Take a look at the Powershell solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169220/export-query-result-to-csv-file-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: For some reason, my Powershell SQL addins are not installed. -- Is there any other method I could accomplish this task?

Comment: Are the databases on the same server? Are the table names the same between all the dbs? If the answers to both questions are `yes`, then I'd put all the db names in a table, and use that table and your existing query to build and execute dynamic sql. Then I'd put the whole thing into a SQL Agent job and give it a schedule to run on.

Comment: Can the SQL Agent Job export to a CSV once it finishes running the query?

Comment: No, but you could create an SSIS package that the job would run. The package would use the same technique I mentioned above, and it would also be able to write the results to a .csv.