# Output Query into CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Can someone help point me in the write direction. I want to schedule this query to run and out put to a csv. How can I adapt the query to output to a csv?

```
SELECT d.result1
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS result1
   FROM
     ( SELECT test.dbo.OrderedDocuments.UserDocumentID,
              test.dbo.OrderedDocuments.OrderGroupID,
              test.dbo.OrderGroups.TimePlaced
      FROM test.dbo.OrderedDocuments
      INNER JOIN test.dbo.OrderGroups ON test.dbo.OrderedDocuments.OrderGroupID = test.dbo.OrderGroups.OrderGroupID
      WHERE test.dbo.OrderGroups.TimePlaced >'2018-05-17') mySubQuery) d
```

Comment: What DBMS? What layout of CSV? What example input data, current output. and desired output? Right now it looks like you want a CSV with one column, which isn't really a CSV, is it?

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL Managment Studio 2016. I just need the result in a comma delimited CSV in order that I can ingest into a digital dashbard.

Comment: What result? `d.result1` is a single column, so there's nothing to separate, was my (pedantic?) point.

Comment: OK. The full query uses CROSS JOIN's to gather the same information from multiple databases. Is then displays the results for each database in a column. Currently I run this in SQL Managment Studio, I get a column for each database telling me the order total for a given time period. Just looking to automate this a litte. Thanks for you help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export query result to .csv file in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169220/export-query-result-to-csv-file-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Use SQLCMD utility and SQL Server Agent to automate this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a SSIS package and schedule it.

1. Right click database you are using > Tasks > Export Data
2. Check server, authentication, and database details are correct > Next
3. Select Flat File Destination as the destination, and enter the file name of the csv file you wish to output to > Next
4. Choose the second option, to write a query > Next
5. Enter the query > Parse to ensure the query is valid > Next
6. Click Preview to ensure the data is what you expect > Next
7. Click the 'Save SSIS Package' checkbox > Select where you want to save it
8. Give the file a name> Next
9. Double check the package > Finish

Use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-2017#SSMS) for reference on how to schedule a job using SQL Server Management Studio

Then Just Schedule the Job, SQL Select SIS Package you just created.