# Is there a way to export query results to a CSV through query itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, export-to-csv

I want to export the results of a SQL Query to a CSV file in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, but not through the GUI. I want to do it automatically through my actual query. Is there an "Export to CSV" statement I can use in SQL Server? I have searched online and am only finding sites talking about how to export results to CSV through the GUI.

**ANSWER**

I utilized Powershell which is found in the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169220/export-query-result-to-csv-file-in-sql-server-2008/12950723#12950723) down in the below post:

[Export query result to .csv file in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169220/export-query-result-to-csv-file-in-sql-server-2008)

```
$AttachmentPath = "CV File location"
$QueryFmt= "Query"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Server -Database DBName -Query $QueryFmt | Export-CSV $AttachmentPath
```

Comment: The third answer down might. But what goes in the `$QueryFmt` variable. Do you know?

Comment: that is a powershell variable where you add your query between both ""

Comment: but the 4th answer seems better suited

Comment: Answer 3 worked great. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Crimp, but note that answer positions are subject to change, both over time and based on one's "Sorted by" setting. I assume you meant [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950723/45375), right?

Comment: Correct. I have also posted the answer in my description

Answer (score 1):

Can you try if this will work on your side.

Use the SQLCMD utility to export the result of a query to a CSV file.

```
sqlcmd -S <SERVERNAME> -d <DATABASENAME> -E -s"," -W -Q "SELECT * FROM <TABLENAME>" -o "C:\PATH\TO\FILENAME.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have different ways

1.sqlcmd

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16

example:

sqlcmd -S .
-Q "select * from Employees;"
-o "C:\employees.csv"
-W
-w 1024
-s ","
-h-1

sqlcmd is the command name.
-S . specifies the server name.

-Q "select * from Employees;" is the query that fetches data to be exported.

-o "C:\employees.csv" defines the file that stores the exported data.

-W removes the trailing white spaces you see in the command line tool output
after each value.
-w 1024 defines the length of the line in the CSV file.

-s "," defines the separator for the column values; here, a comma.

-h-1 removes the header.

2.SSIS

you can export data to a csv file using an SSIS package

[https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7209/export-data-to-excel-from-sql-server-integration-services-package/#:~:text=Double%2Dclick%20on%20the%20Flat,Delimited](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7209/export-data-to-excel-from-sql-server-integration-services-package/#:%7E:text=Double%2Dclick%20on%20the%20Flat,Delimited)

3.C#