# sql server importing excel data with merge cells

Tags: sql-server, import-from-excel

i have a set of excel data containing merge cells that needs to be imported into sql server. However, the results of import show null for cells that are merged.

i have tried using IMEX function, testing with values 0,1,2. but it still imports merge cells as null. is there a way to this? thank you

```
SELECT * INTO BenchmarkSurvey FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Data Source=C:\Benchmark Survey\Received\Survey1009.xls; Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;IMEX=1"')...[Sheet1$];
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170621212839/https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/ten-common-sql-server-reporting-services-challenges-and-solutions/#hr4).
Moreover, you can also try to export the excel file to a CSV file and then import it to SQL Server

Edit: this link may be of use: [merged cells behavior](https://web.archive.org/web/20151210014557/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/chrisbal/archive/2006/07/08/659545.aspx)

Comment: seems like your is helpful for reporting.
but i wish to import data into SQL Server.

Comment: OK, try exporting the table to .csv and importing it to SQL Server then. You can do it programatically (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd) or you can use the GUI (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

Comment: or is it feasible to use rownumber(), and update cells with previous row data if it is null?

Comment: If you know what to put in null rows, sure.

Comment: I have imported a set of data from excel with merge cells into sql server.

in the sql table, it now contains:

period | product ID | price | qty
2006   | 123     | 100   | 1
null   | null       | null  | 2
null   | null       | null  | 2
2007   | 321        | 20    | 1
null   | null       | null  | 2
null   | null       | null  | 2
null   | null       | null  | 2

i wish to populate null values based on the previous row record.
I attempted to assign row number, but can't do an 'over' syntax, being afraid it might change the order of raw data.
So how do i go abt this?

Comment: First of all, create a duplicate of that table to avoid losing data.

Comment: Secondly, i think you'll need to use a loop to run through all the records in the table and then use a query resembling this: