# Single and double ticks within a string, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, escaping, ssms

I want to set my @query field within a stored procedure to the following:

```
sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS databases, create_date from [?].sys.tables where DATEDIFF(day, create_date, GETDATE())<7'
```

My basic understanding of SQL may be way off, but can I do the following? (for sp_send_dbmail in case anyone is wondering) Or does this not work, since sp_msforeachdb is also a procedure itself?

```
@query = 'sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS databases, create_date from [?].sys.tables where DATEDIFF(day, create_date, GETDATE())<7''
```

If this is legal,how can I escape the single and double ticks within the string because I keep getting errors, such as Incorrect syntax near ''' or something simmilar. Thanks so much!

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server  (and I'm out of close votes).

Comment: @MarcB, maybe we can give you a new alias. The Closer :)

Comment: I tried this actually, can I also escape double quotes by...doubling them up?

Comment: what about this one brian? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253814/insert-double-quotes-into-sql-output

Comment: And I still am not sure if this is actually allowed as an input to @query? Thanks for your help by the way!