Adding double quatation mark (") into query value (first column problem) that is send by email in csv file
I am trying to add double quotation mark to my SQL query result that is send by email as a csv file. I tried doing this with concat and by adding ''"''+ to the column, but the first row of values is always without quotation marks. This is the first row of my query:
        SELECT
            ''"''+''"First Name"'' as [First Name]
            ,''"name1"'' as [name1]
            ,''"name2"'' as [name2]
            ,''"type1"'' as [type1]
            ,''"Quantity"'' as [Quantity]
            ,''"type2"'' as [type2]
            ,''"type3"'' as [type3]

And the result in my csv file is like this:
First Name","name1","name2","type1","Quantity","type2","type3"
The first quotation mark is missing, i tried even adding more of them or different combinations but in every output i got this without " at the start, other columns works fine.
Tried combos with adding ''"''+, concat, adding more than one double quoatation marks etc.

maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253814/insert-double-quotes-into-sql-output

Why are you putting the quotes in your SQL at all? It's the extract process that should be quote identifying the data, not the SQL statement. Smells like an XY Problem.

I will check that first answear, couldnt find it

I need quotes in output - faport receiver requires that form of raport in csv, with "" and comma as separator
