Add double quotes around each field in export
I have this select clause for a bcp export. Been playing around with different combinations but cannot seem to get double quotes in the output. Wondering if anyone could assist. This is an SP and is used in a SQL agent job

SELECT CONCAT(
 'ISNULL(',
 CASE
 WHEN id IN () THEN QUOTENAME(name)
 ELSE 'CAST(' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' AS VARCHAR)'
 END,
 ', '''') + ''',
 @Delim + ''','
)
FROM table c
WHERE column = 'test';      


Output is currently
 Name|Name|Name etc
Needed output
"Name"|"Name"|"Name" etc

this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253814/insert-double-quotes-into-sql-output

Consider using a better tool such as Powershell and DbaTools' commands: Export-DbaDbTableData or Invoke-DbaQuery and pipe to Export-Csv

Note that tables have columns, not fields.

Please read [mre]

quotename(name) will result in [Name], not Name. Is this actual code you are running?

As you ask and as I understood you: to add double quotes around each field in your export for example as you mentioned: Name|Name|Name to "Name"|"Name"|"Name" in SQL, you are recommended to change - your SELECT to include the double quotes directly in the string.
In your code, change quotename(name)  to QUOTENAME(name, '"') to wrap your column values ​​like Name|Name|Name to "Name"|"Name"|"Name" with double quotes.
And add '"' + to QUOTENAME(name, '"') and what comes out at the end is
`'"' + QUOTENAME(name, '"') + '"'`

This ensures that each name value is enclosed in double quotes.
Correct code that came out at the end:
SELECT CONCAT(
 'ISNULL(',
 CASE
 WHEN id IN () THEN '"' + QUOTENAME(name, '"') + '"'
 ELSE 'CAST(' + QUOTENAME(name, '"') + ' AS VARCHAR)'
 END,
 ', '''') + ''',
 @Delim + ''','
)
FROM table c
WHERE column = 'test';

