# How to generate a csv file using select query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to export data as CSV format from SQL Server using sqlcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd)

I want to generate CSV file using select query in SQL-server.

The code below is working correctly in mySQL:

```
select * into outfile 'd:/report.csv' fields terminated by ',' from tableName;
```

It generated the CSV file.

Does anybody know how  can I create a CSV file using select query in SQL-server?

Comment: There is a SSMS 2008 addin tool that does this for your tables that can be customized by where and order by clauses. http://store.nmally.com/software/sql-server-management-studio-addons/ssms-addin-scripting-tool-insert-to-t-sql.html

Answer (score 15):

Will this do the work

```
sqlcmd -S server -U loginid -P password -d DBname -Q "select * from tablename" -o output.csv
```

**EDIT:**

Use `-i` options if you want to execute a SQL script like `-i sql_script_filename.sql`

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLCMD -S MyInstance -E -d sales -i query_file.sql -o output_file.csv -s
```

You can use `OPENROWSET()` to *read* from a CSV file within a T-SQL query but AFAIK you can't write to one. This is really what SSIS/DTS is for.

If you're working with it interactively in SQL Server Management Studio you could export a grid to a file.