# Retrieve duration query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL 2005 server. I have a database by name STAT & 2 columns by name STARTRUN & ENDRUN and have many rows in it.

```
   STARTRUN     ENDRUN
20110910200007  20110910200017
20110910200028  20110910200037
20110910200048  20110910200057
```

It shows the start time and end time of an activity and is in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format. The datatype for this column is VARCHAR. I am trying to write a SQL script where i can retrieve the duration of each activity and dump it to a csv file as shown below.

```
START DATE  START TIME      END DATE    END TIME    DURATION
10-09-2011  8:00:07 PM      11-09-2011  1:10:10 AM      5:10:03
```

Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Where exactly are you having difficulties?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this should be datetime, why then use varchar for fixed length character data?

Comment: Agreed gbn. Datetime or at least bigint (8 bytes either way). Datetime would make the solution much less complicated.

Answer (score 1):

First you'd have to find a way to convert your format to a `datetime`.  The subquery below does that by making it look like an ODBC canonical date and then calling [`convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  Then you can combine more `convert` with `datediff` to get your desired output format.

```
select  convert(varchar, startrun, 105) + ' ' + 
        substring(convert(varchar, startrun, 109), 13, 8) + ' ' + 
        substring(convert(varchar, startrun, 109), 25, 2)
,       convert(varchar, endrun, 105) + ' ' + 
        substring(convert(varchar, endrun, 109), 13, 8) + ' ' + 
        substring(convert(varchar, endrun, 109), 25, 2)
,       substring('0' + cast(datediff(hh, startrun, endrun) 
            as varchar), 1, 2) + ':' +
        substring('0' + cast(datediff(mi, startrun, endrun) % 60 
            as varchar), 1, 2) + ':' +
        substring('0' + cast(datediff(s, startrun, endrun) % 60*60 
            as varchar), 1, 2)
from    (
        select  convert(datetime,
                substring(startrun,1,4) + '-' +
                substring(startrun,5,2) + '-' +
                substring(startrun,7,2) + ' ' +
                substring(startrun,9,2) + ':' +
                substring(startrun,11,2) + ':' +
                substring(startrun,13,2),
                120) as startrun
        ,       convert(datetime,
                substring(endrun,1,4) + '-' +
                substring(endrun,5,2) + '-' +
                substring(endrun,7,2) + ' ' +
                substring(endrun,9,2) + ':' +
                substring(endrun,11,2) + ':' +
                substring(endrun,13,2),
                120) as endrun
        from    @YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Here's a [working example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112277/)  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd) for exporting the result of a query to a CSV file.