# Trying to create a batch file exporting using 'sqlcmd' to a CSV

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to export data as CSV format from SQL Server using sqlcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd)

I'm trying to create a .bat file to query from a database using `sqlcmd`. This is what I got so far using sources online:

```
sqlcmd -S servername\sqlexpress -d DNAME -U username -P password
-Q "SELECT 1,2,3,4,5
    FROM table1
    SELECT 6,7,8,9,10
    FROM table2
    BACKUP DATABASE [DNAME] TO DISK = 'C:\test.csv'"
```

If I run this at its current state the CSV file isn't being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch files do not have free whitespace, so you cannot just insert line breaks where you want.  Put all the code in a single line instead.

Comment: I have removed the spaces however it still does not create a csv file. I'm very new to batch files and sqlcmd's as I just started but I appricate the help I have recieved