# Writing sql data from a procedure to flat file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am using sql server 2008 and (c#, asp.net). How do I write a select statement result to a text file (table with 5 columns and 30+ rows) in sql server? I have a database with hundreds of tables and stored procedures.

Comment: Related thread- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd

Comment: I would have to create a job that would call execute a command line for bcp to write a file. Isn't there another way I can do this (similar to a stored procedure)?

Comment: I'm not sure but have a look at this thread - http://serverfault.com/questions/210526/ms-sql-server-2008-how-to-export-all-the-tables-into-csv

Comment: Since your using C#, you can easily write the results of your query out using a DataReader (e.g. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/58/Exporting-data-to-a-CSV-tab-delimited-or-other-text-format).

Answer (score 1):

You can run the select through ISQL via `xp_cmdshell` and use the -o parameter to output the results to a file. This example uses the -E parameter to avoild hard-coding a userid.

```
declare @str varchar(255)
select @str = 'isql -Q "select * from <tablename>" -E -o c:\text.txt'
exec master.xp_cmdshell @str
```