# how to export sql output to excel with text format

Tags: sql, export-to-excel

I have requirement that,  Need to export the sql output data to excel sheet. To acheive this i am executing the below query,

```
xp_cmdshell'sqlcmd -s  -U aaaa -P bbbbb -d dbao -Q " set nocount on;select * from table_tmp" -s "," -o D:\temp_table.xls
```

The query is executing fine but the issue which i am facing while executing that query is,

I am loosing the extract format of the columns

E.g., 0000012345 is stored as 12345  ( since it is numeric value xls by default removing preceeding zero's.

Is there a way to load the data in excel with format as text.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you morph that columns content into a string inside the SELECT command?

Comment: Is you're output a csv, and you're opening in excel?

Comment: I am opening in excel only.

Comment: and if youre opening in notepad, then you do or don't see the precending zeros?

Comment: Just follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd) ,hope it helps.

Comment: I did not try opening that file in notepad. And i think if we open a xls in notepad it will not be in readable format.

Comment: I think @Mask's link will help... Go for it...

Comment: Ifyou can maybe possible to make the columnvalues surrounded with " Like "00125" now excel know this is a string

Comment: @Mask . the link which you provided is really help full. but i am not sure which option will make data to store in text format. is that -C or -V