# Copy large record data from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, bigdata

Client need with round 500,000 data in csv/xlsx format for every two month, which we currently follow the procedure by manually copy 60,000 records one time in csv/xlsx then download after passing multiple servers and finally merge all csv/xlsx in one csv, their is also chance of error while compiling all data.
We need shortcut for copying large amount data(round 500,000 records) from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 in one time.
Please suggest better way.
Thanks

Comment: if you must do it from sql server, just create linked servers in ssms and union them all, and save the output as CSV.

Comment: Can't you just bulk export the whole data in CSV format to a shared folder and fetch that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd