# Getting data from shell script to sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bash, shell

I have two servers - one Windows server with SQL Server Express and one Linux server.
On the Linux server I have a shell service which is waiting for a new folder. After something is added it checks if it's OK and after that it should create a new record, for example in table `customer` it should create a new customer.

I already have the first part but I don´t know how to get the data from the shell script to the SQL Server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using bash script to connect to remote db server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664515/using-bash-script-to-connect-to-remote-db-server)

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the steps below

1. Setup a share on the Windows server accessible to the Linux server
2. Have your Linux script generate a CSV file of the data to be inserted and push it to the Windows server share via SMB.
3. Write a Windows batch file or powershell that you setup as a scheduled task on whatever interval you want that iterates over each file in the Windows directory dropped by the Linux process and calls `BCP` to insert the data.
4. Move the processed files to an archive directory as part of the windows batch file.

For documentation on using BCP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx