# Strip unneeded info from the exported CSV file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I'm using this batch script to export the result of SQL-script in a tab-delimited CSV.

```
sqlcmd -S PRISHA-CRM  -i "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.sql" -U essl1 -P essl  -o C:\outputfile.csv  -s " "
```

[image: screenshot]

1. How to prevent the second row `----------` from appearing in the exported file?
2. How to prevent the text in `B4` cell from appearing in the exported file?

Tried multiple things but it's not working.

Comment: please see image for output format

Comment: Show us the things you have tried and specify how they are not meeting expectation.

Comment: Check the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd

Comment: What is "**tab**-delimited **C**SV"?? note that the '**C**' stands for "**C**omma"...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the dashed lines then pipe your output to the **FINDSTR** command and then redirect to the output file.

```
sqlcmd -S PRISHA-CRM  -i "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.sql" -U essl1 -P essl -s " " | findstr /R /C:"^[^-]*$" >C:\outputfile.csv
```

Don't know anything about SQLCMD so I don't know why you are getting data in B4.

Comment: Hi its not working with data ... need Tab delimited .. only colum hedding is coming that to not in proper format