# How to create txt or csv file by tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a temp table in sql server 2008 and I need to create a csv of txt file by tsql from that temp table.

What is the correct way for it?

Thanks.

Comment: No it's not, i need to create file by code, The link you send tells how to create by manangment studio tools. thanks anyway.

Comment: I removed my vote.

Comment: Look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd

Comment: Actualyy I need to make it using sql query:)

Comment: AFAIK you need to use a tool for this, q.v. [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/writing-select-result-to-a-csv-file), you can't just write a basic query from the studio.

Comment: You can write a select query including all the fields you need and Go to Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results To Text. When you run the query it will prompt you to save the file. I guess it will let you save the file in rpt or txt format. You can open it via excel or a text editor. There are few ways of exporting this is one of them. Not recommending this for huge datasets. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1 + "," + col2 
from table
```

send results to file

Comment: You have that in detail in a comment.  Show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide tempdb.. it can access temp tables

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp " select * from tempdb..#tables" queryout c:\test.txt -c -T'
```

Comment: When I try to --> 
** 'bcp "select filecontent from tempdb..#tempbanktable" queryout "D:\test.csv" -c **
I am getting this error --> ** Error = [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Code page 857 is not supported by SQL Server **

Comment: ]which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: looks like codepage issue.. Try using '-w' parameter