# SQL Server into outfile QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi guys I need to make a query that exports a **csv file**. Sadly the `select * into` file is not working.

Comment: use bcp command.

Comment: Please refer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/writing-select-result-to-a-csv-file

Comment: Can't use BCP due to the fact that it is external utility, not built in the language.

Comment: what's wrong with using external utility ?

Comment: What environment are you running the query in?  SQL Server Management Studio?  A client application that you've written yourself?  Where do you want the output to be written, the server or somewhere local?  The normal use-case is that you want the results to be written locally to whatever process is submitting the query.  In which case ***THAT*** process should take the result set and write it to a file itself *(SQL won't do that)*.

Comment: When asking, it is better to also include the exact code you have tried and why it does not work as well as your desired output.

Comment: Automation software I use won't let me use it. https://imgur.com/a/PmwCouH Here is the list of what I can use

Comment: @AdamDominiak - edit your question with the additional information (not an image or picture link) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss like I said there is no additional info. When I use the BCP command it won't let me pass through.
Command construction is like so:
$DBExecute("NAME_OF_CONNECTION_WITH_DB","STANDARD SQL QUERY") I just can't use bcp. Any other way?

Comment: But you added a link to a picture in a comment, extract that, add your information to your question that you have in comments.  ALSO as it stands this seems like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/425379/125981  If not, add that link in your question and why THAT does not work (as well as similar answers) - see, that is what is meant by additional information...As it stands, your question is likely to get closed as "unclear", "too broad" or a duplicate of some other question like that one. Comments are NOT part of your question.