# SQLCMD changes "7 k" string to 7k or 7,000?

Tags: csv, sqlcmd

I have a SQL query that returns a value similar to "7 KI" for a description column, but when I export my data to a .csv/text file using SQLCMD, the resulting data is "7KI" (no space inbetween 7 and K). I believe that this causes a formatting issue when I open this csv file in Excel later on...(I'm wondering if "7K" is getting read as 7,000 because the data is splitting into a new column as-if it contained a comma there?)...

This is so weird to me.  I am using the Quotename function to return the Unicode version of this description field in the first place - do you think that's why I am experiencing this issue? I used the Quotename function to fix issues with this field a few days ago. To me, it's odd that the export is stripping the space inbetween 7 and K in the first place.

Has anyone ever seen/fixed this before? It really looks like there is a space included in the SQL data, and I copied-and-pasted the value into a online Unicode converter to confirm there is a space. Why would a random space be getting stripped in the SQLCMD export? Plenty of my other text fields are not having this issue, even though they have spaces too (although not followed by  "K"...) so maybe the issue is with CMD somehow reading the value...?

Comment: Does [How to export data as CSV format from SQL Server using sqlcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976218/1115360) help?

Comment: Hmmm...I think I read that earlier; initially I don't recall it answering this question, but let me read through it some more and see of I can find an answer. Thanks for the reference!