# How to Query and Export Large Data Set in Python Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas

I have SQL Server Database Table in Amazon RDS and I am running a python script on a 8 GB server in AWS EC2. The python code simply select all the data in a large table and tries to convert it into EC2. The EC2 instance quickly runs out of memory even though I am trying to extract the data yearly, however I would like all the data to be extracted into a csv (I don't necessarily need to use Pandas)

As of now the pandas dataframe code is very simple

```
query= 'select * from table_name'
df = pd.read_sql(query,cnxn)
df.to_csv(target_name, index=False)
```

The error I am seeing is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       df = pd.read_sql(query,cnxn)
>     MemoryError

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use your SQL database's native management tools instead of Python/Pandas here.

- If it's a MySQL database,
  `mysql ... --batch --execute='select * from table_name' > my-file.csv`
- If it's a PostgreSQL database, within `psql` do something like
  `\copy (select * from table_name) To './my-file.csv' With CSV`
- If it's SQL Server, [(via here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd)
  `sqlcmd -S MyServer -d myDB -E -Q "select * from table_name" -o "my-file.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700`

If you really *do* want to use Pandas though, you might be able to get away with [the `chunksize` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql) (adjust accordingly if you're running out of memory):

```py
with open('my_csv.csv', 'w') as f:
    for i, partial_df in enumerate(pd.read_sql(query, cnxn, chunksize=100000)):
        print('Writing chunk %s' % i)
        partial_df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=(i == 0))
```

Comment: The solution without Pandas seems the right way. I've read some community posts and it seems to fetch the entire data set even with Chunksize to Memory, which is a problem because as soon as my big table is dumped in Memory, I am getting MemoryError. Maybe this has something to do with my DB Driver, not sure about that. But thank you for sqlcmd, this came in Handy.

Source: https://gitter.im/pydata/pandas?at=554609295edd84254582fb39
Source: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10693

TBF, I am surprised the Keyword says Chunksize but doesn't work like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `read_sql` with pandas, you certainly have a driver that allows you to directly query the database with a DB-API 2.0 interface, and then write with the csv module one record at a time:

```
con = ...   # it depends on your currect driver
curs = con.cursor()
curs.execute('select * from table_name')
with open(target_name, 'w', newline='') as fd:
    wr = csv.writer(fd)
    wr.writerow([d[0] for d in curs.description])    # write the header line
    while True:                                      # loop on the cursor
        row = curs.fetchone()
        if not row: break                            # until the end of rows
        wr.writerow(row)                             # and write the row
curs.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, however seeing as my table is too big this seems like it will take too much time and consume too much server resources writing a few million lines.

Comment: @RakeshGuha: Why do you think that? Whatever the way, the system will write the data. And all decent system (Python is) know to optimize line access at a point where it is close to raw access. And as this solution uses little memory, the system can use more for its own buffering...

Comment: Thank you, I will try this, check the system stats and let you know, I don't have a sandbox environment that's why I didn't want to take a chance, will run this and vmstat to check the more suitable option for me.