# how to get excel file from query in SQL automatically?(For Example Every 1 Hour in one Destination.)

Tags: sql

this is my data

```
select productid,productname from product
```

Comment: It depends on what database you use, what IDE you are using? Can you please tag the database

Comment: The question need more details like sql type, Operating system, etc

Comment: This is typically provided by the SQL client software that you use to access your (undisclosed) database.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Microsoft SQL Server, you can use  "sqlcmd" command line tool.

See example here

[How to export data as CSV format from SQL Server using sqlcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd)