# Perl: how to export data from SQL Server into tab delimited txt file using perl

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I am writing a perl script where it connect to SQL server. I've compose a query that will get the data that I need. But in perl, how can I export the data from SQL into tab delimited txt file using perl ?

here is my sample script:

```
my $sql = "SELECT top (20) [code] AS Code
      ,Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
      (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
      ([name],'\“','\"'),'\”','\"'),'<= ','&le;'),'>=','&ge;'),'<','&lt;'),'>','&gt;'),CHAR(10),'<br>'),'\n',' '),CHAR(13),' '),'–','-'),'’',''+NCHAR(39)+'') AS ShortDesc
      ,Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
      (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
      ([description],'\“','\"'),'\”','\"'),'<= ','&le;'),'>=','&ge;'),'<','&lt;'),'>','&gt;'),CHAR(10),'<br>'),'\n',' '),CHAR(13),' '),'–','-'),'’',''+NCHAR(39)+'') AS LongDesc
      ,CASE WHEN isobsolete = 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'Y' END AS Obsolete
      
FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY effectivefromdate DESC) rn, * 
     FROM [CodingSuite_STG].[Codes].[Hcpcs] ) cs
     WHERE  rn=1 
     order by code asc";
     
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

 
#Execute the statement
$sth->execute();


while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
     print "@row\n";
}

#Close the connection
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to just use `bcp`, exporting data to files is what it does best.

Comment: Hello can you elaborate your answer please

Comment: Your question is not complete. Some DBs allow to extract information into external file and specify delimiter. Please check [SELECT ... INTO Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html). There is a very high chance that you do not invent something what is provided by DB.

Comment: Skip the Perl part and let the database do it for you so it handles all the weird cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd/425463

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try and use [`join()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join). Something along the lines of:

```
...

my $fh;

if (!open($fh, '>', "/path/to/file")) {
  die($!);
}

while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
  print($fh, join("\t", @row) . "\n");
}

close($fh);

...
```