# SQL Server BCP export file incremental

Tags: sql-server-2012, bcp

I'm trying to use `BCP` to export my data to a `.TXT` file, but I needed to do an incremental in the same file, since I will need to export data from two views.

Example:

```
 SET @cmd = '"SELECT * FROM Site"'

 SELECT @sql = 'bcp '+@cmd+' queryout D:\mytest.txt -c -t; -T -S SERVER-PC\SQLEXPRESS';

 EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql;


 SET @cmd = '"SELECT * FROM Customers"'

 SELECT @sql = 'bcp '+@cmd+' queryout D:\mytest.txt -c -t; -T -S SERVER-PC\SQLEXPRESS';

 EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

Data out:

```
 H;04399024100427;20160620
 V;04399024100427;CUSTOMER I;STATE;CITY;NAME;75123390;A
```

I thought of UNION ALL but the structure of the tables are different and I have cases where I will need to export data from up to 5 tables.

Comment: You can still create a view to union your tables, just cast all columns to varchar and include placeholders of null or blank strings.

Comment: The problem is that the table that contains the fewest fields will appear in the delimited field, with the amount of columns existing at the junction of the two tables.

Comment: I managed to solve it by creating 3 files, each according to its table structure and then joining the 3 files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export data as CSV format from SQL Server using sqlcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd)

Comment: T-SQL is not the place for firing off command shells. I'd suggest you use [the Powershell answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976218/14868997), along with the `-Append` option for `Export-Csv`, this will append to the existing file.